How can I force React Native FlatList to display only one image at a time in horizontal landscape mode
Right now I am facing this issue in my React Native FlatList rendering.  As you can see in the screenshot, multiple images are displayed side by side in landscape mode.

Is there a way to avoid this situation?  I just want ONE image to be displayed in landscape mode each time.
My FlatList implementation looks like this:
<FlatList
      testID={FULLSCREEN_GALLERY_IMAGE_LIST_TEST_ID}
      ref={listRef}
      data={images}
      style={styles.list}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      initialScrollIndex={initialImageIndex}
      getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
      renderItem={renderImageItem}
      snapToAlignment="start"
      decelerationRate={'fast'}
      snapToInterval={width}
      viewabilityConfig={imageListConfig}
      onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
      horizontal
      nestedScrollEnabled
      scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
      disableIntervalMomentum
      extraData={extraDataFlatList}
    />


How do you get the width?
like this? const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

@ZhivkoNikolov Dimensions.get('window');

well I can't be sure but you can try to place it in useState
like: useState(Dimensions.get('window'))
and then to have in useEffect something like
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', setDimensions(Dimensions.get('window'));
and ofc remove the listener in return of the useEffect

another suggestion: use this instead const { width } = useWindowDimentions();
I think this won't need to have a useEffect for transitions

I tried useWindowDimensions(), it didn't change anything...

well this:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions
you can use it for images width and height when the phone flip
Edit: editing the whole comment is not nice :/
